# Pass css classes to Ransack's sort_link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Working on a RoR project for myself (self-teaching), now toying with Ransack which is an awesome gem...

I would like to have a few "sort_links" on top of my index page - work as expected, but I can't figure out how to style these links.
Have tried this but didn't work:

```
<%= sort_link(@q, :title), class: 'btn btn-info btn-small') %>
```

The wiki and readme of ransack don't really talk about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ransack option hash before the html options hash. You can take a look at [this code](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/0bd4afeaac70030b11074e814f090e8fd3131e67/lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb#L47) if you want to see what the sort_link helper is doing.

Ransack V3

```
<%= sort_link(@q, :title, class: 'btn btn-info btn-small') %>
```

+1 Luke pointed out you no longer need an empty hash, thanks!

Ransack V1 & 2

```
<%= sort_link(@q, :title, {}, class: 'btn btn-info btn-small') %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fyi. Ransack version 3 resolved the issue where an empty hash was required.

So using `<%= sort_link(@q, :title, class: 'btn btn-info btn-small') %>` works.